# pl/sql if statement failing on incorrect if condition

Tags: oracle, plsql

apologies if this is covered elsewhere, i'm not sure what to search for. I'm having trouble with a pl/sql block.

The issue is with the IF statement below. Even when the condition (r) is not met, the script bottoms out as it attempts to run the block anyway.

I have encountered similar issues before, and resolved by putting select statements into variables and then executing the variables, however i can't get that to work in this instance. Has anyone seen this before, and any idea on how to resolve?

```
sqlplus -s xxx << EOSQL
    set serveroutput on feedback on termout on
    DECLARE
        r number;
    BEGIN
        SELECT count(*) INTO r from sys.dba_audit_mgmt_config_params WHERE AUDIT_TRAIL = 'UNIFIED AUDIT TRAIL';

        IF (r > 0) THEN
            dbms_output.put_line('-- UNIFIED_AUDIT_TRAIL is in use, setting timestamp and purging');
            DBMS_AUDIT_MGMT.set_last_archive_timestamp(
                        audit_trail_type  => DBMS_AUDIT_MGMT.AUDIT_TRAIL_UNIFIED,
                        last_archive_time => SYSTIMESTAMP-30);
            DBMS_AUDIT_MGMT.clean_audit_trail(
                        audit_trail_type        => DBMS_AUDIT_MGMT.AUDIT_TRAIL_UNIFIED,
                        use_last_arch_timestamp => TRUE);
        ELSE
            dbms_output.put_line('-- UNIFIED_AUDIT_TRAIL not in use, skipping');
        END IF;
    END;
/
EOSQL
```

Another example of this can be seen below, this time using a SELECT statement to highlight the issue, the table RANDOMTABLE does not exist purposfully to highlight the issue.

```
sqlplus -s xxx << EOSQL
    set serveroutput on feedback on termout on
    DECLARE
        r number := 0;
        s varchar(200);
    BEGIN
        IF (r > 0) THEN
            dbms_output.put_line('-- UNIFIED_AUDIT_TRAIL is in use, setting timestamp and purging');
            select count(*) into s from randomtable where object_name = 'BANANAS';
            dbms_output.put_line(s);
        ELSE
            dbms_output.put_line('-- UNIFIED_AUDIT_TRAIL not in use, skipping');
        END IF;
    END;
/
EOSQL
```

Which fails with:

```
DATABASE:/apps/ora/home> ./test1.sh
            select count(*) into s from randomtable where object_name = 'BANANAS';
                                        *
ERROR at line 7:
ORA-06550: line 7, column 41:
PL/SQL: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
ORA-06550: line 7, column 13:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
```

And finally, the below works as expected, returning the ELSE block output. This time the table definitely DOES exist.

```
sqlplus -s '/ as sysdba' << EOSQL
    set serveroutput on feedback on termout on
    DECLARE
        r number := 0;
        s varchar(200);
    BEGIN
        IF (r > 0) THEN
            dbms_output.put_line('-- UNIFIED_AUDIT_TRAIL is in use, setting timestamp and purging');
            select count(*) into s from dba_objects where object_name = 'BANANAS';
            dbms_output.put_line(s);
        ELSE
            dbms_output.put_line('-- UNIFIED_AUDIT_TRAIL not in use, skipping');
        END IF;
    END;
/
EOSQL
```

Comment: what do you mean "bottoms out?"

Comment: Are you saying that - although R = 0 (as it can't be less than 0, and can't be NULL), the "unified_audit_trail is in use" part of code is being executed? Did you display R's value right after you selected it? Perhaps it isn't 0, after all?

Comment: Bottoms out - fails - as the unified_audit_trail isn't being used when r = 0.

Comment: It also fails when explicitly setting r = 0

Comment: Removing the dbms_audit clauses entirely, explicitly setting r = 0 and inserting the following, allows the if statement to complete as expected.             dbms_output.put_line(r);

Its worth noting that i've been seeing similar behaviour with select statements where the tables don't exist.